# Generate an array that statisfies some conditions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to generate a 3 dimensional array that satisfies the following conditions:

1. for every sub 2D array, the sum over their respective rows and columns must be less than 1;
2. for these same sub 2D arrays, the some of all of their components must also be less than 1;
3. every element must be less than 1.

For example, consider a 2x2x2 array. Then the two 2x2 arrays (that I called sub arrays) must satisfy the two conditions above.

I tried solving this with a rejection method like:

```
while done == False:
    array = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(2,2,2))*(1/100)
    c1 = condition1(array) # returns True is condition 1 is satisfied
    c2 = condition2(array) # returns True is condition 2 is satisfied
    if c1 == True and c2 == True:
        done = True
```

The problem with this is that it takes too much time to find a solution, and I need to repeat this process with 4 and 5 dimensional arrays. Also, later on I will have another constraint to add to this problem, but one thing at a time!

Comment: If by component you mean matrix element and the values in the matrix are actually all positive, as your sample-code implies, then condition 2 would be sufficient to guarantee condition one and three.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is start of with a 1xC vector initially, then transform it to a NxN matrix (where N**2 = C). In code, it would look something like this:

```
N = 2 # Preferred sub matrix size
C = N ** 2
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, C)) # Generate uniform vector
a /= a.sum() # Normalize elements such that they sum to 1
a -= np.min(a) / 2 # Decrease every element by the minimum divided by 2 to make the sum less than one
a = a.reshape(N, N) # Reshape matrix
```

Here we normalize the vector to make the elements sum to one, then subtract each element by the minimum of the vector divided by 2 and reshape the vector to fit your sub matrix size. This process should be repeated N times to acquire an NxNxN matrix and you should stack the resulting sub matrices to acquire your 3D matrix.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Sorry for the late reply, busy times. One question: is the a -= np.min(a) / 2 necessary if I want the sum to be equal to 1?

Comment: @fregtd If you want the sum to be equal to exactly one, then you can remove that line. However, if you want the sum to be less than one, then you should subtract the minimum divided by some amount larger than 1 (in this case it was 2) from all elements in the vector.